# Extracting information from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have thought about a few approaches to this coding problem but none has yielded any results so far. 
I'm aware of the subset function but it seems inadequate to carry out the exact task below.

Given the data frame A below, I wish to obtain a second data frame with negative numbers closest to zero for each category changed to zero. For example for category A1, we have -4 changed to zero for category B10, -3 is closest to zero hence we change it to zero, etc.

For example:

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")
y_1 <- c(1, -4, -10, -3, 5, 8, -9, -11)
A <- data.frame(x_1, y_1)

x_2 <-  c("A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")
y_2 <- c(1, 0, -10, 0, 5, 8, 0, -11)
B <- data.frame(x_2, y_2)
```

As you can see, I only want the negative numbers closest to zero in y_2 to be changed to zero whist other numbers can stay the same. It seems like a simple coding task and I'd appreciate any assistance with it.

Thanks

Comment: I presume you mean negative and closest to zero?

Comment: The number closest to zero for 'A1' is '1', isn't it? Why is '-4' changed to '0'?

Comment: @James and Arun, sorry about the mistake. Yes I do mean negative numbers closest to zero-I've edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")
y_1 <- c(1, -4, -10, -3, 5, 8, -9, -11)
A <- data.frame(x_1, y_1)

x_2 <-  c("A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")
y_2 <- c(1, 0, -10, 0, 5, 8, 0, -11)
B <- data.frame(x_2, y_2)
```

Something like this?

```
library(plyr)
tmpfun <- function(d) {
    negy <- d[,2]<0    ## negative values
    w <- which.max(d[negy,2])  ## closest to zero
    d[negy,2][w] <- 0
    d
}
ddply(A,"x_1",tmpfun)
```

Comment: What happens if there are two negative y's to replace? What does the OP want?

Comment: @Ethan. If there are two negative numbers to replace and they are both the same (say, -6, -6), we can make them both 0. If they're not the closest negative number to zero gets replaced by 0. I hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: changing `w <- which.max(d[negy,2])` to `w <- which(d[negy,2]==max(d[negy,2])` should change the behaviour as specified above (`which.max()` only returns the first index, `which(...)` returns all indices)

Comment: @BenBolker, Thanks for answering my question. The code you've supplied works for the data I've provided with my question, however, I cant get it to work for my original data. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Are there any scenarios where the above code wouldn't work?

Comment: @BenBolker, I think you omitted a bracket in your comment above.w <- which.max(d[negy,2]) to w <- which(d[negy,2]==max(d[negy,2]) should read w <- which.max(d[negy,2]) to w <- which(d[negy,2]==max(d[negy,2])). Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: yes, I missed a bracket. The only thing I can think of offhand that might mess this up would be `NA` values.  Otherwise, though, you'll have to try to work some more to find a minimal example that fails ...